# How to develop an augmented reality application for Android indoor systems?

Tags: android, mapping, augmented-reality, indoor-positioning-system, android-augmented-reality

I need to produce an augmented reality app for indoor environments. I've done some experiments using Wikitude, but this solution works best in outdoor environments, and work with the use of markers for indoor environments, which greatly complicates the analysis. The reason work is an experiment that takes hold, where I am trying to have some virtual elements inside a building, to be seen during the walk. I do not have a very thorough knowledge of programming, and the solutions found to enable faster and simplified implementation are for outdoor environments. Already researched tools like Look! Augmented Reality, but I was instructed to seek a newer solution. Because of Pokemon Go, it has been easier to find material and tutorials to implement this technology in outdoor environments and almost anything in indoor environments.I am trying to work on a solution for Android systems. I have used Android Studio and also the ARAF, in addition to working with Wikitude. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Anybody can help me?

Comment: Indoor AR without markers is a though order. Not knowing what your aiming for makes it even harder. The easiest thing would be when you can afford special hardware, like hololens or google tango, which has enviroment awarness. The next best thing is to use single camera SLAM. A workaround might be using image markers